# Turn QGIS .vrt raster file to 1s and 0s

Tags: qgis, gdal, raster-calculator

I'd like to turn all (valid) values in a virtual raster to 1s and all null values to 0. I've run a script from OSGeo4W which divides height values by themselves and the results are fine, but can take a while with some larger .vrt 's.

I'm looking for a more elegant (computationally simple) solution to this problem. The null values to 0 is optional, they can stay as null values.

Comment: RoVo - Yes, ideally

Answer (score 4):

**gdal_translate** can convert an input image to a 1 Bit image with `-co NBITS=1`. All values above 1 will be cut and set to 1, all values below will be 0.

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -ot Byte -co NBITS=1 in.vrt out.tif
```

If you have 0 and negative values as valid values and your null-value is e.g. -9999, you can use **gdal_calc.py**

```
gdal_calc.py -A in.vrt --outfile=out.tif --calc="(A>-9999)" --NoDataValue=0
```

Comment: Thanks RoVo, but as explained I want all positive and negative values as 1 (ie all actual values), and no data pixels as 0.

Comment: I updated the answer